# How can I filter a data table based on input from a Leaflet map within R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am making a dashboard using shiny that will have a leaflet map and a data table. I would like to be able to click on a polygon from the map (i.e. a specific county), store the county as a reactive value, and then filter the data table to show only results for that county.

I would also like the data table to show all rows by default if no polygon is clicked, and to go back to showing all rows if the polygon is unselected.

Here is a basic working example I've created. I am able to click the map and get the correct county, but I seem to have a problem storing the value in `click_county`.

```
lapply(c('data.table','dplyr','ggplot2','shiny','shinydashboard','leaflet','DT',
         'USAboundaries','sf'), library, character.only = TRUE)

ca_counties <- USAboundaries::us_counties(states = 'CA')

parcels <- structure(list(county = c("Yuba", "Sacramento", "Inyo"), num.parcels = c(27797L, 
                                                                                    452890L, 6432L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

parcels <- st_as_sf(left_join(parcels, ca_counties[,c('name')], by = c("county" = "name")))
parcels_df <- parcels
parcels_df$geometry <- NULL

#====================================================================================================

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = 'green',
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('Use of Force Incidents', tabName = 'dallas_maps', icon = icon('city'))
  )),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    #===== Dallas Map Tab =====#
    tabItem(tabName = 'dallas_maps',
            fluidRow(
              box(
                width = 12, collapsible = T,
                title = 'Dallas County Census Block Groups',
                solidHeader = T, status = 'primary',
                leafletOutput('parcels_map')
              )
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(
                width = 12, collapsible = T,
                title = 'Use of Force Incidents, 2014 - 2016',
                solidHeader = T, status = 'primary',
                dataTableOutput('parcels_table')
              )
            )
    )
  ))
)

#====================================================================================================

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #===== Dallas Map Tab =====#
  # Map of Census block groups
  output$parcels_map <- renderLeaflet({
    bins <- c(1, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 600000)
    pal <- colorBin("Blues", domain = parcels$num.parcels, bins = bins)
    
    labels <- sprintf(
      "<strong>%s County</strong><br/>
      Parcels: %g<br/>",
      parcels$county, parcels$num.parcels
      ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    
    leaflet(parcels) %>%
      setView(-119, 37.9, 6) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(
        layerId = ~county,
        fillColor = ~pal(num.parcels),
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        color = 'black',
        dashArray = '2',
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "red", weight = 3,
                                            bringToFront = TRUE),
        label = labels,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "4px 8px"),
          textsize = "15px",
          direction = 'auto')) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~num.parcels, opacity = 0.7, title = "Number of Parcels",
                position = "bottomleft")
  })
  
  click_county <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$parcels_map_shape_click, {
    # Capture the info of the clicked polygon
    click_county <- input$parcels_map_shape_click$id
  })
  
  print(click_county)
  
  # Parcels data table
  output$parcels_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(parcels_df,
                  # colnames = c(''),
                  options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100),
                                 pageLength = 10,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = '_all'))),
                  filter = 'top')
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried something like this for rendering the data table so I can get all rows by default and just the filtered rows upon clicking the map:

```
# Parcels data table
output$parcels_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  if (is.null(click_county())) {
    DT::datatable(parcels_df,
                  options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100),
                                 pageLength = 10,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = '_all'))),
                  filter = 'top')
  }
  else if (!is.null(click_county())) {
    DT::datatable(parcels_df[parcels_df$county == click_county(),],
                  options = list(lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100),
                                 pageLength = 10,
                                 columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = '_all'))),
                  filter = 'top')
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Hunter ! I'm trying to do the same thing in my shiny App but I was wondering how you could have made this script worked since your "parcels" data is a dataframe... 
The part leaflet(parcels) ..... shouldn't be working right ?

Comment: @wanderzen I just reran this and it seems to work fine for me. In my code, I have parcels (which is an sf object) and parcels_df (which is a dataframe). parcels is used in the leaflet chunk and the parcels_df is used to make the data table output. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the syntax `click_county(input$parcels_map_shape_click$id)` to assign a value to `reactiveVal`.

Here, I remove filter by re-clicking on same county, as I could find the event of clicking outside of a county:

```
  observeEvent(input$parcels_map_shape_click, {
    # Capture the info of the clicked polygon
    if(!is.null(click_county()) && click_county() == input$parcels_map_shape_click$id)
      click_county(NULL)     # Reset filter
    else
      click_county(input$parcels_map_shape_click$id)
  })

  # Parcels data table
  output$parcels_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable( 
      if(is.null(click_county())) 
        parcels_df    # Not filtered
      else 
        parcels_df %>% filter( county==click_county())
        )
  })
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and was much simpler than I thought. Thanks.